# How to automate telnet and ftp in windows vbscript effectively with using wscript sendkeys

Tags: windows, scripting, vbscript, telnet, wsh

I am running the following VBScript file:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run("telnet.exe 10.10.10.10")
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys"root"
WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys"root123"
WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys"cd /code && make"
WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 5000
WshShell.SendKeys"ls -lrt"
WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
```

But I feel that, while executing, this it will pop up command prompt. It will keep on sending keys to the command prompt windows at an interval of 500 milliseconds. While doing this if I click another window, than this script will start sending keys to that other window instead of the command prompt.

Is there any other way to do telnet automation without SendKeys function?

Answer (score 0):

Just use **appActivate** before sendKeys.

Answer (score 0):

simply, you need to do it in "silent mode" or "back-end" .... but don't ask me how! i am looking for it too :)

you might need to check this ...
[How to run telnet in silent mode using VB script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546970/how-to-run-telnet-in-silent-mode-using-vb-script)