# How to run telnet in silent mode using VB script?

Tags: vbscript

I am new in VB scripting. Actually i want to run some telnet commands of application server.

I am running that VB script on my client PC (OS:- Windows server 2003). The script is working well.

Now the issue is that while the telnet is running via VB script, i can not do anything else on that

PC. And i want that script to be run at backend. i.e in silent mode.

Following is the VB code that i am using.

```
set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run"cmd.exe"
WScript.Sleep 500
oShell.SendKeys"telnet x.x.x.x -f roamingsubscriber.txt"
oShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1500
oShell.SendKeys"username"
oShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
oShell.SendKeys"password"
oShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
oShell.SendKeys"command"
oShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys"command"
oShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
...
```

Answer (score 1):

See this site `http://www.dimac.net/default3.asp?M=FreeDownloads/Menu.asp&P=FreeDownloads/FreeDownloadsstart.asp` for a free ActiveX compont that does this kind of thing.
Here is the API

```
http://www.dimac.net/products/freeproducts/w3sockets/reference/refstart.htm
```

Here some sample code

```
Set oSocket = WScript.CreateObject("Socket.TCP")
oSocket.DoTelnetemulation = True
osocket.Timeout = 1000
oSocket.Host = "host.somewhere.com" & ":" & 80
oSocket.Open
oSocket.SendLine("GET /" & vbCrLf)
data = oSocket.GetLine
If (Instr(data, "yourtest")) then
    ' doSomething
End if
oSocket.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to accomplish you task until you find or develop an `ActiveX` component that will start `telnet` process without creating a console window and pipe its input and output over a pipes. At least `WScript.Shell` does not provide such functionality.